# BackboneJS: How to assign multiple models in a single view

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backbone-views, backbone.js-collections, backbone-model

How do you call multiple models in a single view

Usual case is that you create a backbone model

```
var myModel = Backbone.Model.extend({ url:"api/authentication"});
```

and then assign it to a view, making it the default model of a certain view

```
    var LoginView = Backbone.View.extend({
        model: new myModel(),
        initialize: function(){
            _.bindAll(this, 'render', 'render_thread_summary', 'on_submit', 'on_thread_created', 'on_error');
            this.model.bind('reset', this.render); 
            this.model.bind('change', this.render); 
            this.model.bind('add', this.render_thread_summary); 
        },
        ...
    });
```

But I have many methods in a single view that calls different models. Currently I just create an instance of a model inside an event method.

The other solution that I'm thinking would be like this

```
initialize: function(){
   _.bindAll(this, 'render', 'render_thread_summary', 'on_submit', 'on_thread_created', 'on_error');
   new.model1().bind('reset', this.render); 
   new.model2().bind('change', this.render); 
   new.model3().bind('add', this.render_thread_summary); 
},
```

But are these good practices? What else are the other way to do this. Thanks.

**UPDATE**
In response to Peter, here's my actual code

```
var userRegModel                = Backbone.Model.extend({url: fn_helper.restDomain()+'user/reg'});
var userResendActivationModel   = Backbone.Model.extend({url: fn_helper.restDomain()+'user/token/activation/new'});
var userResetPassModel1         = Backbone.Model.extend({url: fn_helper.restDomain()+'user/pwdreset/token/new'});
var userResetPassModel2         = Backbone.Model.extend({url: fn_helper.restDomain()+'user/pwdreset/change'});
var userLoginModel              = Backbone.Model.extend({url: fn_helper.restDomain()+'user/login'});

_view:  Backbone.View.extend({
                el:             'div#main-container',
                initialize:     function(){},
                events: {
                    'click #user-signup':            'signupUserFn', //userRegModel 
                    'click a#activation-resend':     'resendActivationFn',//userResendActivationModel
                    'click #reset-password-submit1': 'execResetPasswordFn', //userResetPassModel1
                    'click #reset-password-submit2': 'execResetPasswordFn', //userResetPassModel2
```

Each models declared above corresponds to different methods  declared in events

Answer (score 4):

- Normally model instances should be passed to views in the `options` argument to the `initialize` method.

Generally models represent data that either is currently or will eventually be stored in database somewhere. Now, sometimes you want to create a model just for managing ephemeral browser state, which is fine, but the common case is that most read/edit/delete views don't create models unless that's their primary purpose like a "Post New Comment" form. So normally if your view has to show some models, allow them maybe to be updated and saved, they should come into the view in the `options` argument to the `initialize` function.

However, if your view really needs so many models and nothing else in your system cares about them, just create them during `initialize` and store them directly as properties on `this` (your view instance) and off you go.

If you post a more complete code sample, we can give specific recommendations, but as it is it looks like if you have a `LoginView` and you need more than 1 model for it, you might be off in the weeds design-wise.

**Part Deux**

OK, so it looks like you think every API endpoint needs a model. Just implement those as methods on a single model class that use `Backbone.sync` with the appropriate `url` option.

```
var Model = Backbone.Model.extend({
    resendActivation: function () {
        return Backbone.sync.call('update', this, {url: fn_helper.restDomain()+ 'user/token/activation/new'});
    }
});
```

You may have to do some manual triggering of events and I'm not sure what your API returns, but fundamentally these are all dealing with a single user record and can be handled by a single model.

Misc unrelated tips:

- `_.bindAll(this);` //don't bother listing methods out
- `this.model.on('reset change', this.render);` //bind multiple events at once
- JavaScript by vast majority convention use camelCase not lower_with_underscores